# Gettin 500 Internal Server Error in rails on ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, railscasts

I'm trying to create a record from a form. I've used railscast 136 as ground work. When I trying to submit I get a 500 error for missing partial. I've created the controller correlated javascript view but it is requesting a view with the same name as the model.

**error message**

> Rendered appointments/create.js.erb (3.8ms) Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 12ms
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial appointments/appointment
>   with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb,
>   :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:   *
>   "/Users/gjores/Sites/Rails/verkstad_test/app/views" ):
>       1: $('#appointments').append('<%= j render(@appointment) %>');   app/views/appointments/create.js.erb:1:in
>   `_app_views_appointments_create_js_erb___2325925946390315228_70273089113920'
>   app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:16:in`create'

**Controller**

```
 def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])
    if @appointment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to new_appointment_path, :notice => "Successfully created appointment." }
        format.js
      end
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

**appointments/new.html.erb**

```
<div id="appointments">
    <%= render 'shared/appointment_part' %>
</div>
<% title "New Appointment" %>
<table>
<% @students.each do |s| %>
<%= form_for @appointment,  :remote => true do |f|%>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <tr>  
    <td><%= s.name %></td>
    <td><%= f.label :week %></td>
    <td><%= f.number_field :week %></td>
    <td><%= f.label :teacher_id %></td>
    <td><%= f.collection_select(:teacher_id, Teacher.all, :id, :name) %></td>
    <%= f.hidden_field :student_id, :value => s.id %>

  <td><%= f.submit %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<% end -%>
</table>

<p><%= link_to "Back to List", appointments_path %></p>
```

**appointments/create.js.erb**

```
$('#appointments').append('<%= j render(@appointment) %>');
```

**Routes**

```
    appointments GET    /appointments(.:format)          appointments#index
                 POST   /appointments(.:format)          appointments#create
 new_appointment GET    /appointments/new(.:format)      appointments#new
edit_appointment GET    /appointments/:id/edit(.:format) appointments#edit
     appointment GET    /appointments/:id(.:format)      appointments#show
                 PUT    /appointments/:id(.:format)      appointments#update
                 DELETE /appointments/:id(.:format)      appointments#destroy
        teachers GET    /teachers(.:format)              teachers#index
                 POST   /teachers(.:format)              teachers#create
     new_teacher GET    /teachers/new(.:format)          teachers#new
    edit_teacher GET    /teachers/:id/edit(.:format)     teachers#edit
         teacher GET    /teachers/:id(.:format)          teachers#show
                 PUT    /teachers/:id(.:format)          teachers#update
                 DELETE /teachers/:id(.:format)          teachers#destroy
 notice_students POST   /students/notice(.:format)       students#notice
        students GET    /students(.:format)              students#index
                 POST   /students(.:format)              students#create
     new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)          students#new
    edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format)     students#edit
         student GET    /students/:id(.:format)          students#show
                 PUT    /students/:id(.:format)          students#update
                 DELETE /students/:id(.:format)          students#destroy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your stack trace shows

```
Missing partial appointments/appointment
```

So it looks like rails is trying to render a partial called appointments/appointments.html or appointments/appointments.js

Does a file called appointments.js.erb or appointments.html.erb exist?

If not then create it.

I however suspect that what you are trying to do is show your appointment as I think you want the code below to update the html of some element on your page

```
$('#appointments').append('<%= j render(@appointment) %>');
```

I think you need this line to red

```
$('#appointments').append('<%= j render :partial => 'appointments/appointment', :formats => :html %>');
```

Your html view partial should be appointments/_appointment.html.erb

Comment: Yes i got a appointments.js.erb file and the other code is taking the created instance and appending it to a div. just like railscasts #136 suggests.

Comment: $('#appointments').append('<%= j render(@appointment) %>').  I assume this line is injecting HTML into a DIV.  If so then you want to be running a HTML partial 'appointment/appointment.html.erb  and that should just be an html view partial.  Have amended my answer

Comment: Thank you! It was a naming of partials beginners misstake…

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are rendering a partial in a view **appointments/new.html.erb** and not in the controller **create method** .

Since the partial is defined in the view **appointments/new.html.erb**, so the corresponding **javascript view** should be **appointments/new.js.erb**.

Comment: When i changed the name of the "create.js.erb" to "new.js.erb" i get this error. Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template appointments/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/gjores/Sites/Rails/verkstad_test/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:16:in `create'

Comment: I haven't looked at your routes. This is now seems like a routing issue.