# Rails Ajax create a new instance of a model and add a checkbox for it to a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a view that renders two form partials:

matches/new.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'players/new' %>
<%= render 'matches/form' %>
```

matches/form is a form for a new Match. On the form you can add *existing* Players to Teams. The Players collection is rendered as a collection of checkboxes. When the form is submitted, the Teams get created with those selected Players inside them:

matches/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @match do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :team_1 do |team_1_form| %>
        <%= team_1_form.label "Team 1" %><br>
        <%= team_1_form.collection_check_boxes :player_ids, Player.all, :id, :name, include_hidden: false %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
    <%= f.fields_for :team_2 do |team_2_form| %>
        <%= team_2_form.label "Team 2" %><br>
        <%= team_2_form.collection_check_boxes :player_ids, Player.all, :id, :name, include_hidden: false %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Start Match" %>
<% end %>
```

In players/new you can create new Players:

players/_new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @player, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.submit 'Create Player' %>
<% end %>
```

So the idea is, I want to be able to create a Player (which the form does do successfully, by the way) via AJAX and for that Player's checkbox to be added to the Players' checkbox collection in the view without a page refresh.

I've tried a few different things (you'll see a few commented-out things in the create.js.erb file). I've been stuck on this for days and I've googled the hell out of it. Help please!

Github repo: https://github.com/Yorkshireman/foosball

Controllers:

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @player = Player.create(name: params[:player][:name], league: current_league)
        @match = Match.new
        current_league.players << @player
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js   {}
        end
    end
end

class MatchesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @player = Player.new
        @players = Player.all
        @match = Match.new
    end

    def create
        @match = Match.new(league: current_league)

        if team_1_player_ids && team_2_player_ids
            teams = BuildTeams.call team_1_player_ids, team_2_player_ids, current_league
            InsertTeamsIntoMatch.call teams, @match
            @match.save
            render nothing: true
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Please select players for both teams"
            render :new
        end
    end


    private

    def team_1_player_ids
        params[:match] && params[:match][:team_1] && params[:match][:team_1][:player_ids]
    end

    def team_2_player_ids
        params[:match] && params[:match][:team_2] && params[:match][:team_2][:player_ids]
    end
end
```

views/players/create.js.erb:

```
// $("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'matches') %>");
// $('#new_match_div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'matches/new') %>");
$('#new_match').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'matches/form') %>");

// $('#new_match').replaceWith("<p>Replaced</p>");
```

Comment: What happened when your `create.js.erb` only included: `$('#new_match').replaceWith("<p>Replaced</p>");` ?

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial players/_matches, application/_matches with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/andrew/projects/foosball/app/views"
):

Comment: I asked about `.replaceWith("<p>Replaced</p>");` You're reporting for a specified partial.  I'm guessing that's for `$("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'matches') %>");`.  You probably want this: `$('#new_match').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'matches/form') %>");`.

Comment: When using render partial: 'matches/form', no new checkbox appears. A page refresh makes it appear.

Comment: In your `collection_check_boxes` method calls, is `players` a local variable? What value have you assigned to `players`?  If you replace `players` with `Player.all`, you'd probably get the result you expect.

Comment: I had been passing in `players` as a local variable, which was assigned to `Player.all`, so it makes no difference. I've tried just using `Player.all`

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some inconsistencies between the link to your `create_players` branch and the code that you posted in this question.

I checkout out your code at https://github.com/Yorkshireman/foosball/commit/2413eb576f96333acbb02f1bb05689ae1dc47d3e (`temp_branch`), then made the following changes:

1. I replaced both `@cat` and `@dog` with `@player`.
2. I changed the contents of `app/views/player/create.js.erb` to read exactly as this:

   ```
   $("<%= escape_javascript(render @player) %>").appendTo("#new_match");
   $('#new_match').html("<p>Replaced</p>");
   $('#new_match').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'matches/form') %>");
   ```

The second line has no effect on the end result, so it can be removed.

3. In the `PlayersController#create`, I added:

   ```
   @match = Match.new(league: current_league)
   ```

Adding a new player successfully updates the checkboxes.  If those changes do not work for you, then their might a be browser-specific JS problem that you're encountering.

Comment: Thankyou, with your help I finally cracked it! (with a tweak). Some Rails magic was getting in the way. I'm going to construct an answer to post up now.

Comment: I have edited the original question. Answer to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is before any refactoring, but it works.

Thanks to sealocal, the create.js now reads:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @player) %>").appendTo("#new_match");
$('#new_match').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'matches/form') %>");
```

But unfortunately, I don't fully understand what is going on here; I thought `appendTo` would actually render the player checkbox in the browser, but it seems the entire partial has be re-rendered on the next line? Why is this? What does `appendTo` do exactly?

Here's the weird thing - with the PlayersController like this:

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @player = Player.create(name: params[:player][:name], league: current_league)
        @match = Match.new(league: current_league)
        current_league.players << @player
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js   {}
        end
    end
end
```

I was getting the error:

```
 Rendered players/create.js.erb (33.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 314ms (ActiveRecord: 19.8ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial players/_matches, application/_matches with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/andrew/projects/foosball/app/views"
```

So I googled that error code and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497843/gettin-500-internal-server-error-in-rails-on-ajax-request) (not the answer, but where the poster says, on line 3: "it is requesting a view with the same name as the model."). So I figured this must be some Rails magic, inferring the view from the #create method. SO... (drum roll)...

I tried shifting the `@match` line to above the `@player` line and BOOM! It worked!:

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @match = Match.new(league: current_league)
        @player = Player.create(name: params[:player][:name], league: current_league)
        current_league.players << @player
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js   {}
        end
    end
end
```

If I'm honest, though, I'm not *entirely* sure why this works. For now, I have put it down to Rails, but if someone could shed some more light on it, that would be great.

Comment: 1. Changing the order of those lines should have no effect on your app.  They are not dependent upon each other.  You are simply setting instance variables that are passed to the `create` view. 2. Check out the last example of section 3.4.4 in this Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials .  `render @player` renders your `players/_player` partial and your are appending that partial.  3. Study the jQuery examples to see what's happening with appendTo (http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Comment: Shit, you're right about the order of those lines. I need to check the git logs to find out what really made it work.